# ng-if and angular ui $parent error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a simple layout using Angular UI tabs as follows:

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="mainContainer" data-ng-controller="authorization">            
        <tabset ng-if="authorized">        
            <tab heading="Resources" >
                Authorized
            </tab> 
        </tabset>                    

        <div ng-if="!authorized">
            Not authorized
        </div>
    </div>
```

Whenever authorized is `false` "Not authorized" is displayed is expected, but whenever authorized is `true` and tabs are supposed to be display I get this ugly thing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$parent' of undefined
at link (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js:2760:51)
at Q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:49:451)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:56:142
at f (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:43:24)
at Q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:49:392)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:56:142
at f (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:43:3)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:42:180
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:43:422
at y (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js:47:204) <ul class="nav {{type &amp;&amp; 'nav-' + type}}" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical}" tabset-titles="!tabsAbove">
```

I also get the same thing if I use `ng-switch`.

Here is the Angular versions I am using

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js
//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js
```

Seeing how it doesn't look like it's coming from any of my angular code I am not even sure where to start looking for a solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to ensure that the directives `ng-if` and `tabset` do not collide:

```html
  <div ng-if="authorized">
    <tabset>        
        <tab heading="Resources" >
            Authorized
        </tab> 
    </tabset>
  </div>
```

Your problem could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1215).

Comment: @americanslon Tried `ng-show` as well? That does not create a new `$parent` scope and might just work.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, and it works. However ng-show triggers the controllers of whatever is in the tabs, and in my case it's quite a few ajax calls which I'd rather avoid.